# What is the react-app-env.d.ts in a react typescript project for

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I just created a react typescript app  with the create-react-app tool  and i found a file  with name `react-app-env.d.ts` in the project structure. I need to know what is the purpose of this file

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This file references TypeScript types declarations that are specific to projects started with Create React App.

These type declarations add support for importing resource files such as bmp, gif, jpeg, jpg, png, webp, and svg. That means that the following import will work as expected without errors:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
```

It also adds support for importing CSS Modules. This relates to import of files with .module.css,.module.scss, and .module.sass extensions.

[Checkout this blog post](https://www.newline.co/@dmitryrogozhny/how-to-start-new-react-application-with-create-react-app-and-typescript--4298e606)

Comment: why this type declaration should otherwise not work? It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 8):

Exactly as @mazedul-islam said

This file is only for ensuring that create-react-app essential types are picked up by the Typescript compiler. It's better to not remove or change since it might get updated by any possible changes in create-react-app. Next.js does the same thing and its explanation might provide better insight: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#existing-projects

This file has a triple-slash directive which is just referring to a file with some types definitions. You can inspect it or open it directly from the node_module: `node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I found it useful to add the following code to `react-app-env.d.ts`. After installing Typescript to an existing React project I had import errors for all the images I was using, but below solved them.

```
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg"; 
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.jpg";
```