# React can't resolve .tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I made a new react project using `npx create-react-app app-name --template typescript` and it ran fine until I imported another `.tsx` file. Now when I try to import another `.tsx` file it gives me an error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/component' in '/Users/benbaldwin/Desktop/project/frontend/teacher/src'`

The only thing I'm doing differently than normal is the file structure. Since I have multiple react projects in the `frontend` folder that share dependancies I moved the `node_modules` to cover all of those subdirectories. my file structure looks like this:

```
- frontend
  - node_modules
  - project-1
      - public
      - src
        index.tsx
        react-app-env.d.ts
        - components
          component.tsx
  - project-2
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

the component file looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Component: React.FC = () => {
    return <div>hello</div>;
};

export default Component;
```

and the index file looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Component from './components/component';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Component />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

do I need to eject `create-react-app` and write out my own web pack config or is there a better way to fix this?

the full source code is on my GitHub: https://github.com/baldwin-dev-co/mountaineer

Answer (score 16):

I just came across this problem as well, with a brand new React project.

Temporarily downgrading `react-scripts` from version `5.0.0` to `4.0.3` solved it for me, because after invoking `npm install` and `npm run start` this added the missing `tsconfig.json` file - which was the actual cause of the problem.

After this I could safely go back to `5.0.0` and everything worked fine.

Comment: for anyone stuck here, based on Johannes answer i ran `tsc --init` and it created the missing file which solved the issue above.
make sure to first install typescript of course `npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue as well upgrading a project to typescript, using `react-scripts` 5.0.1.

In an attempt to diagnose what was going on, since there are only a few hits on this searching the problem, I setup 2 new projects.

First, is the `npx create-react-app myapp` non-typescript-template project;

- Let it run and install as is
- Builds as expected
- Run `npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`
- Change a file to `tsx`, didn't matter which one, any change had the same result
- No `tsconfig.json` generated (as spoken about in the documentation), build fails with errors `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'E:\create-react-tsx\myappts\src'`

Second, run `npx create-react-app myappts --template typescript` typescript-template project;

- Let it run and install as is
- Builds as expected

Observations;

Copying the generated `tsconfig.json` from the typescript-template project (myappts) to the non-typescript-template project (myapp) didn't resolve the issue. The errors relate to the svg import etc. `Cannot find module './logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Additionally copying the typescript-template project (myappts) `react-app-env.d.ts` over to the non-typescript-template project (myapp) got the project to build.

As an alternative, downgrading to `react-scripts@4` in the non-typescript-template project (myapp), then changing a file to `tsx` and run a build generates the two required files. A subsequent upgrade to `react-scripts` continues to generate successful builds.

There is a bug filed for this issue;

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10951

Further links;

- [What is the react-app-env.d.ts in a react typescript project for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67262914/3747990)
- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/